# Using local python package in bluemix

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud, packaging

I have created package which will be used in an application which will be deployed to bluemix. I have created the package using `setup.py`. How can I use this package on bluemix without registering it on PyPI (Its just for local usage). This is the setup.py file

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name = "models",
    version = "0.0.1",
    author = "Arush Goyal",
    author_email = "arushgyl@gmail.com",
    description = ("Models for complaintResolution"),
    license = "BSD",
    keywords = "model complaintResolution",
    packages=['models', 'tests'],
    long_description=read('Readme.md'),
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Topic :: Utilities",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `vendor` directory in the root of your app and put your package there. The buildpack should install it directly from there because it is designed to work in a disconnected environment if needed.

See https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/tree/master/cf_spec/fixtures/flask_web_app for an example.